# BlogEngine.Net Json Serialization Length Error?

Tags: c#, blogengine.net

I receive the following error when entering the admin posts page:

```
"Message":
"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer.
The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.",
"StackTrace":"   
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)", "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
```

How can I increase the JSON length in BlogEngine.Net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the configuration file by

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is assignment int32.maxvalue to maxJSonLength as 2147483647